# Adding a view as menu item using menu.py in web2py

Tags: python, model-view-controller, web2py

Someone kindly help me understand the models/menu.py file's following code:

```
response.menu = [  
(T('Home'),False,URL('default','index')),  
(T('About'),False,URL('default','what')),  
(T('Download'),False,URL('default','download')),  
(T('Docs & Resources'),False,URL('default','documentation')),  
(T('Support'),False,URL('default','support')),  
(T('Contributors'),False,URL('default','who'))  
]
```

In this,we specify the controller in the URL(eg.default/what). What if I wish to specify a view in this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In this,we specify the controller in the URL(eg.default/what). What if I wish to specify a view in this?

In web2py, URLs don't route directly to views. Rather, they route to controllers, and controllers have associated views (each controller has a default view, but the controller itself can specify any view). If you want to use the URL to tell a given controller to use a view other than it's usual view, you can indicate that via an arg or var in the URL. For example:

```
response.menu = [...,
    (T('About'), False,URL('default', 'what', args='alt')),
    ...]
```

and in the default.py controller:

```
def what():
    if request.args(0) == 'alt':
        response.view = 'default/what_alt.html'
    [rest of controller code]
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony!!That's great. But what is the boolean for in the list  after T('About')?

Comment: The boolean indicates whether that particular menu item is active (i.e., the currently selected item). When set to True, the `MENU()` helper will add a "web2py-menu-active" class to the `<li>` for that item (you can change the name of that class via the "li_active" argument to `MENU()`). Another way to specify the active url is by directly passing it to `MENU()` via its "active_url" argument.

Comment: Agreed, this was very helpful for me too.